# I need a if statement to go between numbers in python

Tags: python

I have these lines of code:

> if X >= 10 and <=50 :

I then want a print statement but this code is just skipped. Help please.

Comment: It's certainly not "just skipped", it's invalid syntax and throws an error.

Comment: Really, does it 14mpi, well I have the code and theres no error.

Comment: The `and <= 50` part is invalid syntax as the `<=` operator always requires two operands. If you don't see an error either your actual code differs or you're executing it in a way that hides the error from you (e.g. inside of a `try/except` block, or using a bad IDE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the variable to be compared for `<= 50` like this

```
if X >= 10 and X <= 50:
```

or this can be written like this

```
if 10 <= X <= 50:
```

Answer (score 0):

change to:

```
if x >= 10 and x <= 50:
```